# Git auto-merge fails (gives conflicts) for almost all files changed in only one branch

Tags: git

Recently I've got strange problems with Git auto-merge. 
I (and one of my colleague) make commits on topic branch but when I try to merge it with our master Git fails to auto-merge almost all files that were changed in master branch and forces me to resolve conflicts manually. When doing this with mergetool there are no conflict shown in files and the file on our topic branch looks the same as the 'base' file. So the resolving is fast but still annoying for bigger number of files. I went through one that kind of merge today (with more than 10 files marked as 'conflicted') and now have one again with even more conflicting files.
I also tried to merge master with our topic branch but the result was the same.

Eclipse actually shows a commit for conflicting files in our temp branch but when comparing file from that commit with this commit parent there are no changes made in this file. The commits where the change is shown is in merge commit made by my colleague (but not shown in list of conflicted files or anything). To be honest I doubt my colleague would even open those files as they have nothing to do with what he is working on (and that's what he says).

What could be the reason of that behavior and how to stop this? The only thing I can think of is some encoding problems that are not shown in mergetool or Eclipse diff but do matter to Git.

Edit: I have checked diff between merge commit in our branch and its parent commits and indeed the problem was due to endlines (git diff showed more than Eclipse compare). The merge commit replaced CRLF to LF. That was something that actually should have happen (we have core.autocrlf set to true in git config) but one of other employes commited with CRLF endlines (he had set core.autocrlf to false in his repository and he didn't know why it was set that way).

Comment: Or perhaps newlines were changed? Whatever it was, please post the answer when you find out.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue on why.

But i had a case once with UTF being different and git would show them as different but no apparent differences visible until i checked the size of the files.

UTF-16 files are larger than UTF-8 files at least if they have the same content.

So perhpas your colleagues editor is saving the files in another standard

Cheers
  Rasmus VOss

Comment: I was thinking along those lines. Perhaps carriage-returns got added or deleted somewhere?